# Understanding differentiation via chain rule in M-Step K-Means clustering

Tags: k-means, self-study

The following slide is from Erik Bekkers's excellent [course](https://uvaml1.github.io/)lesson 9.2

How is it that we can re-write the following?

$||x_n-\mu_k||^2$ as $(X_n-\mu_k)^T(X_n-\mu_K)$

Also I understand how we get the -2 at the front via the chain rule but I am wondering why we don't need to do something further with the $\mu_k$ inside $(x_n-\mu_k)^T$

[image: Derivation of M-step]

Or is this a question for maths stack exchange?